# Python - mysql - logging queries that generate warnings

Tags: python, mysql, logging, pymysql

I have python code that is making mysql calls.  It logs all mysql errors (and sends me a notifiocation on google chat).  However warnings such as this dont get reported which makes sense since they are not warnings.  I would however like the mysql statement logged when there is a warning so I can fix the underlying issue.  What is the best way to find those warnings and get them to the log(with the bad mysql statment

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF3n Cha...' for column 'recipient-name' at row 1")
```

.

```
try:
     cursor.execute(query_string, field_split)
         db.commit()
     except pymysql.err.InternalError as e:
        logger.warning('Mysql Error : %s', e)
        logger.warning('Statement : %s', cursor._last_executed)
        string_google= str(e.args[1] + ' - ' + cursor._last_executed)
        googlechat(string_google)
        return #exit rather then marking report run good
```

Comment: *"What is the best way to find those warnings and get them to the log(with the bad mysql statment "*  [SHOW WARNINGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [catch_warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) from the warnings module. It's a context manager that provides you with a list of the warnings. The code would look something like this:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    function_that_triggers_warning()
    if w:
         logging_function(w[-1])
```